# Proving an inequality $m + n - 1 \leq mn$

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm trying to prove an inequality,

$$ m + n - 1 \leq mn \;\;\;\; m, n \geq 1 $$

For fixed $m$, I can proceed by induction on $n$ (and vice versa). Clearly, $m + 1 -1 \leq m$, and so the base case, $n=1$, holds. Assuming that,

$$m + k -1 \leq mk$$

holds for some $n = k \geq 1$, we can see that,

$$ m + (k+1) - 1 = m + k - 1 + 1 \leq mk + 1 \leq mk + m = m(k+1). $$

So by induction on $n$, the result holds for fixed $m \geq 1$. However, I'm not sure if this is enough. I feel like I need to be doing some *double* induction technique on both $m$ and $n$. Is there a way to go about doing that?

Comment: $(m-1)(n-1)\geq 0$

Comment: Hint: $$(m-1)(n-1)\ge0$$

Comment: note that addition and multiplication are commutative, so the variable names can be swapped in this one.

Comment: Your proof is fine. It's not as elegant as haqnatural's, but it's valid and you don't need double induction. You proved the following family of propositions indexed by $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$P(n): \text{For all } m \in \mathbb{N}, m + n - 1 \le mn$$

Your base case and induction step work for any $m$ without having to resort to induction on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$m+n-1-mn\; =m\left( 1-n \right) +n-1=m\left( 1-n \right) -\left( 1-n \right) =\underset { as\quad 1-n\le 0,m-1\ge 0 }{ \underbrace { \left( 1-n \right) \left( m-1 \right)  }  } \le 0\; \; \; $$

Answer (score 1):

You do not really need two induction stages: For every $m$ we have  (i): The inequality $m+n-1\leq mn$ holds when $n=1,$ and  (ii): By induction on $n$, the inequality $m+n-1\leq mn$ holds for all $n.$ ......Note that both (i) and (ii) are for ALL $m.$  So the inequality in (ii) does hold for all $m,n.$